# what's causing the desktop computer slowness? hard-disk led blinking

Tags: computer-vision

could someone help me with this problem?

i am using a desktop computer. sometimes the computer's very slow - hard-disk led keep blinking and working, while i check the task manager and found the CPU usage is only 5~6%.

what's going on causing the slowness?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple applications open, or are working with a lot of data, or don't have much RAM, chances are very high that the OS is spending all its time paging virtual memory.  You want to avoid this if at all possible.

The *Performance* tab in Task Manager also lists statistics about memory usage.

Comment: thanks for the reply. what tool i can use to find our which program is causing the hard-disk running busy? thanks.

Comment: The OS kernel is the one that does the swapping.  Look at your process list in task manager (*Processes* tab) and sort by memory usage.  That should give you some idea.  If you don't see the memory column, you can choose *Select Columns...* from the *View* menu.

Comment: thanks again, paddy. very helpful. :)